# I can't use Google play games app

Tags: google-play-games

When I open play games it says "this app requires the latest version of Google play games app" but I already updated it's latest version.I cleared data,uninstalled to it's factory version and again updated it but nothing is happening.still facing this problem, I need it's solutions real fast.I can't safe my game progress.so please make a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is go to the `Google Play Store` >> `My apps` tab and see if there are any updates available manually. You can also do so by typing in the specific app and seeing if there's an `Update` option along side `Uninstall`. As I see, the last update was made on June 11, 2015, which was yesterday, if you're in New York like me.  You should try updating again if you didn't since June 11.

If you check and you are updated, you probably have to update [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) here, which was updated on the 4th of June, 2015.

If neither of these methods work, it means Google needs to release another fixed update.

Answer (score 1):

Your Google Play Service App might be outdated.. You just need to update your app..
Goto google play or play store

Search for google play service

And click on update..
And you are done 
Good luck

Comment: Yes you're right.it worked.tnx

Comment: safin: consider marking this answer as correct in order to credit Akshay for their assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is Google Play Services it's not on the lastest version. Search it on Google Play, install it, and open again Google Play Games. If not, restart your phone after installing Google Play Services

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution!

GO to settings --> APPS--> GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES --> UNINSTALL UPDATE

You will be prompt with error on maps etc...click on that or go to play store and look for GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES and click update..

Thats it! I think google should hire me...

Comment: I think you did not read the question carefully, neither you look at answers at all. Reason: 1) OP already did "[uninstall] to it's factory version" which is same as uninstalling update via Settings -> Apps, 2) [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112226/96277) already covered the second part of your answer. So, if you've any step more to add, make it into a comment there. 

Do correct me if I'm wrong.